# One Table, 2 Columns - out of 2 Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need your help.

I tried to combine my tables so that they result in only one table with 2 Columns.

table1: Product

```
ID_Product | Name
1          | Test
2          | Test2
3          | Test3
4          | Test4
```

table2: Purchase_Header

```
ID_Header | Number | Date
1         | 100001 | 2020-01-03
2         | 100002 | 2020-01-02
3         | 100003 | 2020-01-03
```

table3: Purchase_Line

```
ID_Line | ID_Header | ID_Product | Price
1       | 1         | 1          | 0,5
2       | 1         | 2          | 0,6
3       | 1         | 3          | 0,7
4       | 2         | 1          | 0,8
5       | 2         | 2          | 0,9
6       | 2         | 4          | 1,0
7       | 3         | 1          | 0,3
8       | 3         | 2          | 0,2
9       | 3         | 3          | 0,1
```

Joins:

- Product | ID_Product **on** Purchase_Line | ID_Product
- Purchase_Line | ID_Header **on** Purchase_Header | ID_Header

Aim:

- 1 Table with 2 Columns -> ID_Product and Price
- Column ID_Product -> All ID_Product from Table Product -> OR at least IDs which have a price
- Column Price -> the **lowest** Price from the **last** Purchase (last Date) for **each ID** in Column ID_Product

It is possible that:

- a Product was purchased more than once a day
- the Price is different at the same day

```
ID_Line | ID_Header | ID_Product | Price | Date
1       | 1         | 1          | 0,5       |*2020-01-03*
2       | 1         | 2          | 0,6       |*2020-01-03*
3       | 1         | 3          | 0,7       |*2020-01-03*
4       | 2         | 1          | 0,8       | 2020-01-02
5       | 2         | 2          | 0,9       | 2020-01-02
6       | 2         | 4          | **1,0**   |*2020-01-02*
7       | 3         | 1          | **0,3**   |*2020-01-03*
8       | 3         | 2          | **0,2**   |*2020-01-03*
9       | 3         | 3          | **0,1**   |*2020-01-03*
```

- Last Date, product was purchased -> 2020-01-03 for ID_Product 1|2|3 and 2020-01-02 for ID_Product 4
- Lowest Price, on this date

The result should look like:

```
ID_Product | Price
1          | 0,3
2          | 0,2
3          | 0,1
4          | 1,0
```

Hope you can help me

Greetings
Erik

---

Edit: 25.06.2020

Hi, there seems to be a mistake by myself or with the script below.

As mentioned above I have two tables. CSV Link below.

[Purchase_header.csv](https://www.file-upload.net/download-14157612/Purchase_header.csv.html)

[Purchase_line.csv](https://www.file-upload.net/download-14157611/Purchase_line.csv.html)

When I now run the T_SQL Script

````
```
select distinct l.id_product, min(price)
from purchase_line as l
    inner join purchase_header as h on l.id_header = h.id_header
where budat in (select max(h.budat) as [date] from purchase_line as l
inner join purchase_header as h on l.id_header = h.id_header
    where h.ktyp = N'(Invoice)'            
    group by l.id_product)
group by l.id_product
```
````

I receive the Price 660.0 for the id_product (3232,2,0).

It seems, that the price depends on the Header from 2020-04-27 (older date with min Price) instead of 2020-06-11 (newer date with higher Price) and I don't know why! The Script should use the latest header and when there are 2 headers on the same day, then pick the lowest price.

Anyone see my mistake?

Greetings Erik

Comment: Please read the instructions on the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) on how to write a good T-Sql question and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Shouldn't your second sentence state 2 columns instead of 2 rows?

Comment: @DávidLaczkó you are right, thanks. Edited

Comment: What kind of price is "0,3"? That means you must be storing numbers as characters? But I don't know what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: It seems, that i did some mistake or the code didn't work the way it should. I Updated the Post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
select distinct 
  p.ID_Product, p.Name, 
  first_value(pl.Price) over (partition by p.ID_Product order by ph.date desc, pl.Price) Price
from Product p
inner join Purchase_Line pl on pl.ID_Product = p.ID_Product
inner join Purchase_Header ph on pl.ID_Header = ph.ID_Header
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=74f0f26f43a0685bd1551960127d8a05).
Results:

```
> ID_Product | Name  | Price
> ---------: | :---- | ----:
>          1 | Test  |  0.30
>          2 | Test2 |  0.20
>          3 | Test3 |  0.10
>          4 | Test4 |  1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code, I realized it was not deterministic and the results were inconsistent if earlier date of purchase was added with lower price
Updated code + slqfiddle link below:

```
select distinct l.id_product, min(price)
from purchase_line as l
    inner join purchase_header as h on l.id_header = h.id_header
where date in (select max(h.date) as [date] from purchase_line as l
inner join purchase_header as h on l.id_header = h.id_header
    group by l.id_product)
group by l.id_product
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8b2a54/1/0

Comment: p.s. I might not be completely correct here as the question is a 'little' confusing but would accept any criticizing.

Comment: He doesn't want the date to show just the id_product and the price. removing the max date and i think and it will be exactly what he wants

Comment: It seems, that i did some mistake or the code didn't work the way it should. I Updated the Post.